# Get statistics of Number of Active users tagged by their favorites tags in SO

Tags: support, tags, users, tag-watching

Is there a way to get the statistic of the number of users (with a particular favorite tag like `C` or `Action Script`) so we know when is more feasible that I find answers depending on users that could help me. If I ask a question when most users with favorite tags like `C` are active I guess I will get an answer soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show number of active users per top tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175392/show-number-of-active-users-per-top-tags)

Comment: @PaulSweatte I disagree. That's abut users with high scores on tags, while this is about users who have favorited tags.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get favorite tags per user, but there is a way to get common tags among posts by active users:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/395690/select-common-tags-among-users-with-the-most-posts-this-week

as well as tags which have the most active wikis:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/394767/tag-wikis-with-the-most-edits

**References**

- [How can I get a list of favorite/ignored tags?](https://stackapps.com/questions/4160/)