# Show number of active users per top tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I would like to suggest a new feature request to display number of users current active at the moment grouped by top tags.

I suggest the users having the bronze-tag badge should be considered for displaying this statistic, just to give an idea of users online.

This can be displayed in the sidebar on the main list of questions page, or load it in the sidebar on a post page and just show this stat for the tag with which the current post is tagged.

What are your views in this respect?

Comment: why? Do you care/need to know how many users are on java or c++ at any given point?

Comment: @Aboutblank You probably do if you're posting a question in those tags

Comment: "Users online" seems less useful than "Users who posted an answer in the last X day for ABC tag". And we already [have that](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/topusers), unless I'm misunderstanding the request.

Answer (score 6):

I think this will discourage people from posting in tags with less activity. If a user were asking a question about BF, and saw `0 users active in this question`, they would likely either not post, or post on a different site.

Additionally, what does this information tell you? We gain very little from knowing who is active where. If we want to know about a specific person, that information is on their profile.

Edit: We apparently [have something like this ish](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers), though this isn't quite what you're asking.